# Trac Plugin Not working

Tags: python, plugins, webserver, trac

At work we are using Trac on several internal wiki's and an external wiki. REcently we found the need for a new plugin. After we going through a few tutorials we went to install a plugin to make sure it would work. It didn't. We've been going through trying to figure out. Below I will list the steps and various things I did while trying to get it to work.

1) I went to trac-hacks website and downloaded their hellow world plugin, figured I couldn't make a mistake using their code.

2) I compiled and made an egg using python setup.py bdist_egg on the machine where trac is installed, to make sure it's the same Python version being used.

3) I then copied it over to /directory/where/trac/is/plugins/ folder and chmod 755 the file egg file.

4) I then restarted http, unable to find a better way of restaring trac so this may be where my problem is. It didn't work. So I deleted the egg folder in plugins

5) Uploaded it via trac->administration->plugins and restarted httpd again. Nothing.

6) I realized I had to edit the trac.ini file and added helloworld.* = enabled under component and restarted the web server.

It's quite possible it's me but any help would be greatly appreciated!

Its the helloworld plugin from trachack, essentially displays hello world and theres a button. There are no error messages provided, hence why googling was hard.

I'm assuming that it's using root and that's the user I built it with. I will look into seeing if it's anybody else, just taking a quick look though I don't see anything else that could be using it. I only copied the egg file to the plugins folder, I set up another folder elsewhere and built it and cp to the plugins folder. I'm glad to know I was doing that right because looking up documentation on how to restart trac turns up practically nothing, they just say restart trac or restart apache.  I will look into the logs later on tomorrow. Thanks for the replies! Also we are using trac .12.1.

So after looking at the log files it seems that it doesn't even load the plugin, can't find anywhere that says it's loading or any errors with it. Now we have a few trac sites for various projects and one of the sites already has plugins installed so I went there and and put the test plugin there and checked logs and it didn't work either. So I'm just going to conclude it's the plugin or something we already have in place and it's not me. I believe I'm going to try and make one and test it. Thanks for the help!

Comment: more information: which plugin, any errors code snippets you have and can share with us?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you built the egg correctly.  After you copy it into your plugins folder, change the file's owner and group (I'm assuming you're on Linux since you mentioned `chmod`) to match the account that your webserver uses.  I'm not sure if that's strictly necessary, but it's what's always worked for me.

I may be misreading your #4, but it sounds like you copied the whole egg folder to your plugins directory.  Only the .egg file needs to be copied over, it's a self-contained package.  I don't think Trac looks for .egg files in subdirectories.

Restarting your webserver is the easiest way to restart Trac.  Actually, I'm not aware of any other way to do it.

When it comes to plugin problems, Trac's log is usually a very good source of information. I recommend setting Trac's log level to `DEBUG`, then shut down the web server.  Clear out the contents of Trac's log file, then start the web server and make a copy of Trac's log file after the server has completely come back online.  Do this process twice: once with the plugin installed and once without it installed.  The difference in the logfiles should give you a good indication of what the problem is.  Once you get accustomed to what your logs normally look like, you'll be able to read the log in place without clearing it out and generating two versions of it.

By the way, what Trac version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Check the Trac version and downloaded plugin
instead python setup.py bdist_egg try **python setup.py install**

Answer (score 0):

Quite an old thread, but since I ran into the same problem at one point:

Make sure you build the .egg with the **same** Python version that you use to run Trac with!
Backwards compatibility between Python versions does not matter here, because Trac reads information about the Python version out of the .egg file before it even loads it, to make sure it is compatible.

(Small version numbers should not matter, so you should be able to run a .egg with Python 2.7.10 when it was built with 2.7.3, but not when it was built with 2.6.x. Look at the Version number that is written into the .egg file name.)